Strongswan ipsec w/o LAN interface: Tunnel up, but no routing
I need some help in setting up an ipsec site2site-vpn with Strongswan.
The other side insists on a site2site vpn, but on my side I have only a KVM hosted server with a public internet IP interface, so theres is no "real" encryption domain or local subnet I want to connect, just the host itself.
I've setup a UFW roule to allow traffic on the ipsec ports (ufw allow 500,4500/udp) and establishing the tunnel works quite well:
root@server:/etc# ipsec status
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
    mytunnel[1]: ESTABLISHED 28 minutes ago, 89.XX.YY.ZZZ[89.XX.YY.ZZZ]...195.AAA.BBB.CCC[195.AAA.BBB.CCC]
    mytunnel{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: cb15f465_i 26413994_o
    mytunnel{1}:   10.210.8.32/27 === 10.210.8.0/27

But pinging hosts in the subnet 10.210.8.0/27 does not work, tcpdump for ping 10.210.8.1:
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
16:34:58.457551 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62575, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    89.XX.YY.ZZZ > 10.210.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 4872, seq 27, length 64
16:34:59.481571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62774, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    89.XX.YY.ZZZ > 10.210.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 4872, seq 28, length 64
16:35:00.505563 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 62990, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    89.XX.YY.ZZZ > 10.210.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 4872, seq 29, length 64
16:35:01.529521 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63056, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    89.XX.YY.ZZZ > 10.210.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 4872, seq 30, length 64
16:35:02.553527 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63147, offset 0, flags [DF], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    89.XX.YY.ZZZ > 10.210.8.1: ICMP echo request, id 4872, seq 31, length 64

The subnet 10.210.8.32/27 was settled together for our side. However, as explained before, I do not have an network interface with that ip address. So, I've tried setting up a separate ip address for the eth0 interface with ip addr add 10.210.8.33/27 dev eth0, but that didnt change a thing. I also have the option to attach a separate VLAN interface by my hoster to the KVM instance (so I would have an additional network interface to work with), and set that to the staticip 10.210.8.33. Also didnt make the change.
My guess is: There is a route missing for packets going to the VPN tunnel:
root@server:/etc# ip route show
default via 89.XX.YY.ZZZ dev eth0 onlink
89.XX.YY.ZZZ /22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 89.XX.YY.ZZZ

I've tried to set up a route, but didn't manage to find the correct one as I'm new to this. Should Strongswan set up the correct routes in the system? I've tried to switch to Libreswan, but same result.
After googling for this it seems that this is a rather uncommon usecase. Most people are setting up site2site VPNs with LANs or NATs behind it.
Could someone pleas give advice in setting this up correctly?
Thanks in advance!
EDIT: Replying to ecdsa's comment:
You mean add an IP address to a local interface like with ip addr add 10.210.8.33/27 dev lo or dev eth0? Im not sure what you mean with "in your local traffic selector installed".
The table 220 looks like:
root@server:~# ip route show table 220
10.210.8.32/27 via 89.XX.YY.ZZZ dev eth0 proto static src 10.210.8.33

But pings are still not working :/

If you have an IP address in your local traffic selector installed on a local interface (could be lo) when the SA is established, then strongSwan installs a route automatically in routing table 220. However, that will only have an effect if you send traffic from that host itself and a source address is locally selected. Other traffic you'd have to NAT to that IP so it matches the negotiated IPsec policies.

See EDIT above. Could you help me with that?

Problem solved. It was the other side blocking ICMP and TCP connections -.-
Always good to double check the firewall of IT solution providers i guess.
Thanks @ecdsa for the comment, that helped me understanding where strongswan sets up routes!
